# Dependency Injection with Abstract Factory (Unity)

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, abstract-factory

In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758958) I've asked how to register my abstract factory with Unity.

Now I want to use dependency injection.

I have a class like this:

```
 public interface ICarManufacturer
{

}

public class CarManufacturer : ICarManufacturer
{

    private readonly ISportsCar sportsCar;
    public CarManufacturer(ISportsCar sportsCar )
    {
        this.sportsCar = sportsCar;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        sportsCar.Accelerate();
    }
}
```

How can I tell Unity to pass the right sportsCar (BMW or Volkswagen)?

Answer (score 1):

With unity you can either register the types and let unity work out what to inject, or you can create the objects and then ask unity to inject them. To answer your question, you need the latter, so:

You need to register your CarManufacturer type, but you should also register your SportsCar types. Assuming you have two types *BMWSportsCar* and *VWSportsCar* that implement the *ISportsCar*, you will need to register them as named types so you (and unity) can identify them:

```
container.RegisterType<ICarManufacturer,CarManufacturer>()
container.RegisterType<ISportsCar, BMWSportsCar>("BMWSportsCar")
container.RegisterType<ISportsCar, VWSportsCar>("VWSportsCar")
```

When you want to create the CarManufactuer instance, you will need to create a dependency override to tell unity which specific sports car implementation you want to use:

```
//get the BMW sports car from the unity container
DependencyOverride bmw = new DependencyOverride(typeof(ISportsCar)
                             ,container.Resolve<ISportsCar>("BMWSportsCar")); 

//and get an instance of the CarManufacturer class, passing in the bmw instance
ICarManufacturer obj = container.Resolve<ICarManufacturer>(bmw);
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a naming convention to let the Abstract  Factory resolve Dependencies  via Unity in a very clean and simple way. If people are interested: https://dannyvanderkraan.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/real-world-example-of-dependency-injection-based-on-run-time-values/